# Como montar Grid Bootstrap

Tags: html, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Estou tentando montar uma grid usando a doc do bootstrap mas está muito confuso!

A largura máximo do iframe que carrega os forms é de 868px.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é uma simulação abrindo no tablet em pé e gostaria de mudar a forma dos campos.

Somente nos celulares ficar o form ficar full.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que essa visualização do tablet ficasse assim:

1º Row) Nome, deixar o imput no tamanho 6 (metade da tela).

2º Row) Banco, Agencia e Conta, separa-las no tamanho 4, para ficar na mesma visualização da primeira imagem.

To tentando fazer isso, mas já estou com nó no cérebro!

```
<form method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Nome para essa conta</label>
        <input name="nome" type="text" class="form-control" id="" value="" placeholder="Ex: conta principal" required/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="space-4"></div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Banco</label>
        <input name="banco" type="text" class="form-control" id="" value="" required/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Agencia</label>
        <input name="agencia" type="text" class="form-control" id="" value="" required/>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Conta</label>
        <input name="conta" type="text" class="form-control" id="" value="" required/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="space-4"></div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Gerente</label>
        <input name="gerente" type="text" class="form-control" id="" value="" placeholder="Nome / telefone" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="space-4"></div>




</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`col-xs-*` foram descartados no Bootstrap 4 para `col-*`.

Substitua `col-xs-4` por `col-4` e funcionará como esperado.

Verifique aqui o [PEN](https://codepen.io/edsonfilho10/pen/BgQxXN?editors=1010) que fiz para o seu caso

Comment: O problema é que estou sando um admin template, e o bootstrap dele pare que é o antigo. Eu vi seu exemplo, o tamanho para celular ele ainda divide em 3 colunas.

Comment: Da onde vc tirou que col-md não existe no bs4?

Comment: @Tiago como você disse que queria que ficasse como na primeira imagem pensei que era pra dividir em 4 
"Banco, Agencia e Conta, separa-las no tamanho 4, para ficar na mesma visualização da primeira imagem."

Comment: Mas ele existe no 3 e no 4

Comment: @EdsonFilho penas ficar em uma linha quando for celular, mesmo o celular deitado.

Comment: @hugocsl eu que entendi sua questão de forma erronea...rsrs

Comment: @Tiago corrigi o PEN, verifique lá no mesmo link, utilizei col-12 para dispositivos pequenos como o celular deitado ou em pé e col-md-4 para tablets, não estou no telefone, veja se te ajuda.

Comment: @hugocsl https://stackoverflow.com/a/41795300/2848612, na documentação também: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/ em GRID SYSTEM informa. isso o XS, é pq troquei as palavras! o SM e MD continuam.

Comment: @EdsonFilho Como a minha versão é a 3.3.6 não dei certo. Veja https://codepen.io/edsonfilho10/pen/BgQxXN?editors=1010